# Is it possible to include cart on webpage outside Opencart directory?

Tags: php, jquery, opencart

My client wants the mini cart in header to show on all pages, even those not included in shop. Have Opencart installed in subfolder...
www.mypage.com/shop

Rest of webpage is in www.mypage.com/index.php and so on....

Can it be done, and does someone have a solution to post?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to do an AJAX call to the `module/cart` controller, which will display the same output returned to the default theme header http://demo.opencart.com/

```
$.get("http://website.com/shop/index.php?route=module/cart", function(html) {
    // do something with the `html` variable
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that seems to work for displaying the cart, i did this: $.get("http://www.mypage.com/shop/index.php?route=module/cart", function(html) {
  $("#test").append(html); But it doesnt update if i go to the shop and add a product it still shows up empty. Any suggestions? Im not the king of coding so ..... :)

Comment: Hmm not sure to be honest without taking a look at your markup. Could you share the URLs and I'll take a look?